# Unable to display RTSP Live Stream from IP Camera on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a network IP camera which gives H264 stream over RTSP.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rtspplr.app&hl=en on android can play rtsp stream.
VLC on windows can show this live stream. 
But when I try to view in my android app its say "Can not play this video", I have following code:

.java file

```
private VideoView myVideoView;
private MediaController myMediaControler;
private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        url = "rtsp://192.168.5.108:554/rtpstream/config5=r";
        myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);
        myVideoView.setVideoPath(url);

        myMediaControler = new MediaController(this);
        myMediaControler.setAnchorView(myVideoView);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(myMediaControler);

        myVideoView.start();
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
```

Console Output

```
01-11 16:47:29.754 2564-2576/com.example.sahmed.hdvrlitelivetest1 W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (701, 0)
01-11 16:47:40.445 2564-2576/com.example.sahmed.hdvrlitelivetest1 E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
01-11 16:47:40.446 2564-2564/com.example.sahmed.hdvrlitelivetest1 E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
01-11 16:47:40.447 2564-2564/com.example.sahmed.hdvrlitelivetest1 D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: is the ip address local to you?

Comment: @rahul, yes camera is on local network.

Comment: Ok, and is your Mobile phone on which you are trying to run the code connected to wifi for the same network?

Comment: @rahul, i am testing this on my android phone running android 4.4 kitkat and it is connected to wifi with same network as of network camera. I also have given the permission for Internet and network-state in manifest file.

Comment: can you check if the url is getting played on an external software like vlc player? just to confirm if the url is working. Open vlc player > Media > Open Network Stream> and paste your url here in network section to see if its playing.

Comment: it is playable on VLC on windows. I have checked.

Comment: do you found solution?